# How to use tabulate library?

Tags: python, tabulate

I am trying to use tabulate with the zip_longest function. So I have it like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tabulate import tabulate
from itertools import zip_longest
import itertools
import locale
import operator
import re


50 ="['INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01 i\nTel, +31 (0}1 80 61 88 \n\nrut ard wegetables\n\x0c']"

fruit_words = ['Appels', 'Ananas', 'Peen Waspeen',
               'Tomaten Cherry', 'Sinaasappels',
               'Watermeloenen', 'Rettich', 'Peren', 'Peen', 'Mandarijnen', 'Meloenen', 'Grapefruit']

def total_amount_fruit_regex(format_=re.escape):
    return r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*~?=?\s*(" + '|'.join(
        format_(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')'

def total_fruit_per_sort():
    number_found = re.findall(total_amount_fruit_regex(), verdi50)

    fruit_dict = {}
    for n, f in number_found:
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + int(n)
        result = '\n'.join(f'{key}: {val}' for key, val in fruit_dict.items())   
    return result


def fruit_list(format_=re.escape):
        return "|".join(format_(word) for word in fruit_words)


def findallfruit(regex):
    return re.findall(regex, verdi50)


def verdi_total_number_fruit_regex():
    return rf"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(?:{fruit_list()})"


def show_extracted_data_from_file():
    regexes = [
       verdi_total_number_fruit_regex(),
    ]
    matches = [findallfruit(regex) for regex in regexes]
    fruit_list = total_fruit_per_sort().split("\n")
    return "\n".join(" \t ".join(items) for items in zip_longest(tabulate(*matches, fruit_list, headers=['header','header2'], fillvalue='', )))
    

print(show_extracted_data_from_file())
```

But then I get this error:

```
TypeError at /controlepunt140
tabulate() got multiple values for argument 'headers'
```

So how to improve this?

So if you remove the tabulate function. Then the format looks like this:

```
16   Watermeloenen: 466
360      Appels: 688
6    Sinaasappels: 803
75   
9    
688      
22   
80   
160      
320      
160      
61
```

So expected output is with headers:

```
header1  header2
-------  -------
16       Watermeloenen: 466
360      Appels: 688
6        Sinaasappels: 803
75   
9    
688      
22   
80   
160      
320      
160      
61
```

Like how it works in tabulate.

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: why are you doing `tabulate(*matches,...)`? don't unpack `matches`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing a single table to the [`tabulate()`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) function, passing multiple lists results in the `TypeError: tabulate() got multiple values for argument 'headers'` you are seeing.

Updating your return statement -

```
def show_extracted_data_from_file():
    regexes = [
       verdi_total_number_fruit_regex(),
    ]
    matches = [findallfruit(regex) for regex in regexes]
    fruit_list = total_fruit_per_sort().split("\n")
    return tabulate(zip_longest(*matches, fruit_list), headers=['header1','header2'])
```

**Output:**

```
  header1  header2
---------  ------------------
       16  Watermeloenen: 466
      360  Appels: 688
        6  Sinaasappels: 803
       75
        9
      688
       22
       80
      160
      320
      160
       61
```